# Does a npm run-script named "install" has special status?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-run

I have a `package.json` with both

```
"dependencies": {
  "d3": "~3.5.5",
  "forever": "^0.14.1"
},
"scripts": {
   "install":   "make -f install.makefile"
   "data":  "make -f data.makefile core",
   "serve": "node ./node_modules/.bin/forever ./node_modules/.bin/http-server"
```

}

When I check my scripts by running `npm run`, I get :

[image]

I wonder if "install" is a reserved keywords, since it is not grouped with other scripts.

**Is `install` a reserved word with special behavior when in packages.json's scripts object ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

> install, postinstall: Run AFTER the package is installed.

Comment: Thanks, this is important.
So I don't need to do `npm install` + `npm run install`, right ?

Comment: `npm install` will actually run both `npm install` AND THEN `npm run install`, correct ?

Comment: That is correct. It will preform the standard package installation, and then the user defined "install" script afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't reserved, rather it's one of [npm's built-in commands](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Meaning rather then `npm run install`, you'd execute `npm install`.